# 3-Way-Databinding for Single Document instead of Collection using Meteor and Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, data-binding, angularjs-scope

According to the documentation, it is possible to bind a collection to the Angular Scope with

```
 angular.module('socially', ['angular-meteor']);

  angular.module('socially').controller('PartiesListCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.parties = $meteor.collection(Parties);
  }]);
}
```

This works really well when having a list of items I want to display.

But now I want to edit one of those items, which means I don´t have any collection to bind, **but just a single document**

```
 angular.module('socially', ['angular-meteor']);

  angular.module('socially').controller('PartiesListCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.party = $meteor.collection(Parties.findOne({my query});
  }]);
}
```

I need a 3-Way-Binding to have changes from the client immediately saved to the database.

**How is that possible for just one document?**

Comment: i am still unable to get your problem.you can simply retrive the specific object from the collection and can edit it and pass it to the database.it will reflect on the html page.

Comment: I have a sub page for editing, where I just retrieve that single document I want to edit, and not the complete collection again. I can bind it directly to the scope with $scope.party = Parties.findOne({my query}); No problem, but then it won´t be synced with the database when changed in the view

Answer (score 0):

simply pass this into our angularjs function.

```
<div ng-repeat="party in parties">
      <span ng-click="editparty(this)">{{party.location}}</span>
 </div>
```

in angularjs function `this` (which is now `obj`) will contain the `party` object.

```
$scope.editparty = function(obj){

    obj.party.location = "England"; //edit party object

    //pass to our database...

    obj.party = $meteor.collection(Parties.findOne({my query});

});
```

Comment: when I do that, I get "Cannot read name of undefined" and "cannot read length of undefined, where the result of the query is not undefined. I think $meteor.collection requires a collection, and not a singlee doc returned by "findOne". The code you´ve postet has nothing to do with my problem, my problem occurs when trying to bind a single document, and not the collection